# script to tar up multiple log files separately

Tags: linux, bash, tar

I'm on a RedHat Linux 6 machine, running Elasticsearch and Logstash.  I have a bunch of log files that were rotated daily from back in June til August.  I am trying to figure out the best way to tar them up to save some diskspace, without manually taring up each one.  I'm a bit of a newbie at scripting, so I was wondering if someone could help me out?  The files have the name *elasticsearch-cluster.log*.datestamp.  Ideally they would all be in their individual tar files, so that it'd be easier to go back and take a look at that particular day's logs if needed.

Comment: Please show us the working `tar` command for a single log file, and the folder structure.  We should be able to write a bash loop that solves the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a loop :

```
for file in elasticsearch-cluster.log.*
do 
    tar zcvf "$file".tar.gz "$file"
done
```

Or if you prefer a one-liner (this is recursive):

```
find . -name 'elasticsearch-cluster.log.*' -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} tar zcvf {}.tar.gz {}
```

or as @chepner mentions with the `-exec` option:

```
find . -name 'elasticsearch-cluster.log.*' -exec tar zcvf {}.tar.gz {} \;
```

or if want to exclude already zipped files:

```
find . -name 'elasticsearch-cluster.log.*' -not -name '*.tar.gz' -exec tar zcvf {}.tar.gz {} \;
```

If you don't mind all the files being in a single tar.gz file, you can do:

```
tar zcvf backups.tar.gz elasticsearch-cluster.log.*
```

All these commands leave the original files in place. After you validate the tar.gz files, you can delete them manually.

Comment: Interesting. There are some files that are already tared up, but have the same initial filename.  Would it be possible to add the date at the end of the filename, to exclude those files?  Or can I do a nested for loop like: 
`for file in elasticsearch-cluster.log.*
for file != *.gz`

To automate deleting the files, I assume I can just add a rm:
`for file in elasticsearch-cluster.log.*
do 
    tar zcvf "$file".tar.gz "$file"
    rm $file
done`

?

Comment: Use `find -name ... -exec tar zcvf {}.tar.gz {}` instead of `xargs`.

Comment: @Scottie: To exclude the already zipped file with the find method you can do `find . -name 'file*' -not -name '*.tar.gz' -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} tar zcvf {}.tar.gz {}`

Comment: @chepner: Just curious, why do you prefer using `-exec` rather than `| xargs`? It may be a bit shorter, but xargs is more generic in the input that it can accept.